# Why doesn't ThreadLocal use java.util.HashMap to store value, but customize one?

Tags: java

I am reading the source code of java.lang.ThreadLocal, I have two questions  as follows.

1. Why doesn't ThreadLocal  use java.util.HashMap to store value, but customize one ?
2. Why is ThreadLocalMap defined static in ThreadLocal? if not static ,how could it be ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the earliest JDK 1.2 source code, the dates on the code show ThreadLocal came before HashMap.

```
  * <this is HashMap>
  * @author  Josh Bloch
  * @author  Arthur van Hoff
  * @version 1.29, 04/22/99
  * @see     Object#hashCode()
  * @see     Collection
  * @see        Map
  * @see        TreeMap
  * @see        Hashtable
  * @since JDK1.2

  * <this is ThreadLocal>
  * @author  Josh Bloch
  * @version 1.8 07/08/98
  * @since   JDK1.2
  */
```

Since its the same author, I suspect he wrote a specific one and later went on to replace the general one.  I dont know if there was a different implementation of HashMap before this version, but if there was it looks like Josh Bloch didn't want to use it.

Further it looks like `ThreadLocal`'s implementation is optimized by having custom function's like `getEntryAfterMiss` `expungeStaleEntry` etc.  So while there is another Map implementation later that is good for the general case, you have this highly customized map implementation that already works.

As for your second question, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-class-in-java/.

Comment: I looked at JDK 1.2 source code because these classes didn't exist earlier (According to API)

Comment: Couldn't it be that the `@version` date is the creation date of the specified version? If so it wouldn't tell us anything about when version 1.0 of `HashMap` was created and whether it was before or after version 1.0 of `ThreadLocal`. Just a thought.

Comment: Definitely.  Its very circumstantial evidence.  I had a hypothesis of what happened and the evidence I found supported it and didn't contradict it.  (But doesn't prove it)  I bet we could find Josh and ask him though :-)